# omega function question - junior maths test

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-factorization

I was going over some old maths competition questions for *primary* school children. The hardest question on the paper was this...

> The number $2000 = 2^4 \times 5^3$ is the product of seven prime factors. Let x be the smallest integer greater than 2000 with this property and y be the largest integer smaller than 2000 with this property. What is the value of x - y?

I know this has to do with the $\Omega(n)$ function.   I guess I know

- $\Omega(x) = 7$
- $\Omega(y) = 7$
- $x > 2000$ and
- $y < 2000$

Other than that I have absolutely no idea how to solve this other than to write an algorithm.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give us more information about this competition?  What ages were the participants?  Were they allowed to use books or computers?

Comment: It seems that your question is a multiple-choice question from [this document](http://ec-web.elthamcollege.vic.edu.au/snrlibrary/resources/subjects/maths/PastComps/pdf/2001/2001JD.pdf) with choices (a) 100, (b) 64, (c) 280, (d) 203, (e) 96.

Comment: The competition you refer to has got to be one of the funniest I've seen.  It has 30 questions; the last is the question you posted and the first is "37 + 41 equals."  How much time are the participants given to answer it?

Comment: The question is from the Australian Mathematics Competition 2001. (Formally the Westpac Maths Comp I think).  The papers can be found here... http://ec-web.elthamcollege.vic.edu.au/snrlibrary/resources/subjects/maths/PastComps/maths.htm   I think calculators can be used.  Points deducted for wrong answers. I think there was a 90 min or 2hr time limit.  The questions were graduated so as to find mega brains I guess.

Comment: As an aside, ask any Australian aged 30 to 45 about the Westpac Maths Competition.  They will inevitably sprout any number of anecdotes about how well or badly they did and will have an animated conversation about maths for at least 30 secs.

Comment: For information, calculators are not permitted in the Australian Mathematics Competition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an elegant way to find the answer, but let me present the answer for reference.

I used brute force.  Factorizing the integers $1999$, $1998$, and so on, we find that the largest integer less than $2000$ that has exactly seven prime factors is $1984=2^6\times 31$.  Factorizing the integers $2001$, $2002$, and so on, we find that the smallest integer greater than 2000 that has exactly seven prime factors is $2080=2^5\times 5\times 13$.  (Note that $2016=2^5\times 3^2\times 7$ has exactly eight prime factors, and that $2048=2^{11}$ has exactly eleven prime factors.)

Thus, $x=2080$, $y=1984$, and $x-y=96$.

Comment: Thanks.  I wonder if there is a more elegant way since the competition in question has a significant time limit.

Comment: I assume that you've now seen the solution in the official answers you linked to in your comment in the original post.  The solution was essentially an educated brute force method, with no knowledge of number theory needed except for basic divisibility rules.  (And of course, a calculator is necessary given the limited time.)